# What's the grammatical structure behind “etwas + [adjective]-es”?

Tags: phrase, adjective, grammar-identification

I'm not able to relate the grammatical structure behind the following to any of what I’ve learned:

> etwas + [adjective]-es
>   etwas besseres
>   etwas anderes
>   etwas starres

What is it called? Is it a special structure exclusive to *etwas?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to be *etwas **B**esseres*, as the adjective is made into a substantive here. This also works without *etwas*, so there is no special grammar structure behind this.

> Ich habe Besseres zu tun.

I have better **things** to do with my time.
I have some**thing** better to do with my time.

English needs the *thing* as far as I'm aware of. German leaves *thing* out. Though you **can** write, gramatically correct,

> Ich habe bessere Dinge zu tun.

that one sounds stilted. *Something* literally translates into *etwas*, but German doesn't need the *etwas* here. Maybe that's the source of your confusion. German speakers will always assume *etwas* to be a small amount. So the quality changes when *etwas* is used:

> Ich habe etwas Besseres zu tun.

I have some *very tiny, yet better* thing to do with my time.

Comment: Thank you! One small question: how should one determine the ending of such substantiated adjectives? As in this case it is not clear to me why we should assign the neutral gender to Besseres.

Comment: Adjectives don't have a fixed gender, they go along with some substantive. This applies to nominalizationed adjectives as well. Most time, you would use the gender asked for. Consider *Was für eine Antwort erwartest du? – Die Richtige!* | *Wem gibst du dein Jawort? – Dem Richtigen!* | *Was tust du? – Das Richtige!* | *Was tust du? – Richtiges!* The latter one is the plural.

Comment: Why is the plural form different? I see in other cases they follow normal patterns of adjective declension. Isn't it more logical to say Richtigen or Ich habe Besseren zu tun for the plural form, since we say die richtigen Dinge or die besseren Dinge ?

Comment: There is no logic. German is a mess. To be clear *Richtiges* is the plural for *Das Richtige* only. But someone else has to dig out the rule here, I'm a bit lost, too.

Comment: So Besseres also an exception ? In other circumstances we say adj-en for plural ?

Comment: No, the exception is not about the particular adjective but all about the form. I would say it's a plural form because it's a vague count, but someone else may come up with the correct term, "indefinite", "collective" or something like this. Sorry, I'm no grammar crack.

Comment: It's not plural. Plural would be *Bessere*.